# Use a Count field as a row in Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot

Not sure if it is possible but I'd like to have a pivot table that summarizes how many occasions properties have been missed, and then shows the number of times properties have been missed that many times.

What I'm looking to end up with is something like the below:

`TIMES MISSED      PROPERTIES MISSED THAT AMOUNT OF TIMES
1                    102
2                    76
3                    23
4                    11
5                    2`

Information is currently in the following format:

```
UPRN          DATE MISSED
1029292           1/1/2020
1029292           5/6/2020
1010101           1/2/2020
1046353           4/3/2020
3894387           8/2/2020
3894387           7/2/2020
3894387           9/2/2020
```

So this would give the following table:

`TIMES MISSED    PROPERTIES MISSED THAT AMOUNT OF TIMES
    1               2
    2               1
    3               1`

Is this possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: You can right-click the field in a field chooser and select *Value Field Settings...* From there you can choose to display summary of counts.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you ru13r!

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables in Excel can summarize data not only with *SUM* function, but also with *COUNT* and other functions.

Right-click a field in the "Sum values" field chooser and then select **Value Field Settings...** From there you can choose the function to summarize your data (*COUNT* in your case).